# General use of ellipsis in np.einsum

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, tensor, numpy-einsum

I am trying to implement a tensor network kind of calculation using `np.einsum`.
The goal of the calculation is to have a local 2x2 matrix act sequentially on a tensor of size (2,2,2,...,2,2,2) where the number of dimensions can be arbitrary (as long as memory allows).
I have a working naive implementation for a tensor of size (2,2,2)

```
X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
Y = np.ones(2**3).reshape((2,2,2))
Aijk = np.einsum('zi,zjk', X, Y)
Bijk = np.einsum('zi,jzk', X, Aijk)
Cijk = np.einsum('zi,jkz', X, Bijk)
```

As can be seen, the index to be summed over should move to the right for each subsequent calculation. I could generate the appropriate explicit string but I'm wondering if it possible to implement this using ellipses but I am not sure how to specify the index position if the index is not the left- or rightmost index.

```
X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
Y = np.ones(2**n).reshape(shape) # where shape is the appropriate n-tuple
A = np.einsum('a...,a...', X, Y)
B = np.einsum('b...,...b...', X, A) # how do I specify that the summed index of A is the second one?
...
N = np.einsum('l...,...l', X, M)
```

I hope it is clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Read the docs, and make sure you understand alll examples using '...'.  Basically they can be used where the regular rules of broadcasting apply.  You might want to start with test cases that have explicit RHS indices.  Think of them as dimensions whose number shape aren't important to the operation, but for which the pairing across terms is clear.  So no 'pattern matching' beyond the obvious `broadcasting`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take small steps to add ellipsis to your example.

```
In [3]: X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
   ...: Y = np.ones(2**3).reshape((2,2,2))
   ...: Aijk = np.einsum('zi,zjk', X, Y)

In [4]: Aijk
Out[4]: 
array([[[4., 4.],
        [4., 4.]],

       [[6., 6.],
        [6., 6.]]])
```

Making the RHS explicit:

```
In [5]: np.einsum('zi,zjk->ijk', X, Y)
Out[5]: 
array([[[4., 4.],
        [4., 4.]],

       [[6., 6.],
        [6., 6.]]])
```

Replace the repeated `jk` with ellipsis:

```
In [6]: np.einsum('zi,z...->i...', X, Y)
Out[6]: 
array([[[4., 4.],
        [4., 4.]],

       [[6., 6.],
        [6., 6.]]])
```

And trying that with other `Y` shapes (always keeping first dimension, `2` to match on `z`:

```
In [7]: np.einsum('zi,z...->i...', X, np.ones((2,2,2,2)))
Out[7]: 
array([[[[4., 4.],
         [4., 4.]],

        [[4., 4.],
         [4., 4.]]],


       [[[6., 6.],
         [6., 6.]],

        [[6., 6.],
         [6., 6.]]]])

In [12]: np.einsum('zi,z...->i...', X, np.ones((2,3)))
Out[12]: 
array([[4., 4., 4.],
       [6., 6., 6.]])

In [13]: np.einsum('zi,z...->i...', X, np.ones((2,1,2,3)))
Out[13]: 
array([[[[4., 4., 4.],
         [4., 4., 4.]]],


       [[[6., 6., 6.],
         [6., 6., 6.]]]])
```

I think I could use 'zi,z...->...i', 'zi,jz...->ij...', 'zi,jz...->i...j'.  (but I haven't tested them).  But I'm pretty sure I can't use '...i...'.  And in general can't use ellispis to specify the relative location of the summing 'z' dimension.